# How to debug 2 dlls on Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, debugging, dll, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

I have EXE and 2 DLL used by this EXE. All binary were compiled by Delphi XE2.

How to debug 2 DLL at one time while running EXE?

The second IDE can't attach to the process what is under debugging by the first IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact you don't need to do anything special for this to work. You don't need to run multiple IDEs and you don't need to attach to processes. Start debugging your executable and simply step into the code in the DLLs. The debugger takes care of it all for you.

Comment: Look to the my answer for details how to fix the debugger issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved debugger issue by the following steps:

1. Open any source file of each of two DLLs.
2. Add any breakpoint to each of two DLLs (maybe optional step).
3. Run host application on one of two DLLs.

Comment: I think that all you need to do is to make sure that all projects are in the same project group and then compile all projects in that group. None of those other steps are needed.

Comment: No. When I don't open source files from all projects before run - nothing works on the second DLL.

Comment: I've got all projects in a project group and all in the same directory.